# ¿Cómo habilito el origen de datos de visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

[image]

No me permite hacer la conexión con ningun servidor, ya me meti en el link de ahi pero no encuentro como habilitarlo, no  se a que se deverá esto

Comment: que tipo de projecto es?

Comment: @RamiroBarone es visual basic.net aplicación de windows forms.

Comment: lo acabo de instalar y tengo el mismo problema, lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: Solo se puede visualizar con proyectos configurados con .NET Framework, y no con .NET (Core o asi solo). Hay 2 versiones de este,  .NET (.NET Core o solo .NET) y .NET Framework. Checa como generaste el proyecto.

Comment: @AlexCervantes si es el tipo de proyecto que seleccionas al momento de crear, aparecen 2 tipos de winforms, uno con solo .net y el otro con .net framework, el origen de datos solo se habilita con proyectos de .net framework